# Understanding an issue reported by valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind, arm64

I consistently get this trace shown by valgrind. This is an aarch64 system. I want to know if there is anything I can do within my limits to fix this problem, as explained below -

1. Invalid read of size 8 is at lh_delete by ERR_remove_thread_state (in libcrypto) by soap_free (in gsoap) ? There is no relation as far as I know between these two.
2. Invalid read by a function in libcrypto, attempts to read 8 bytes that has been freed again by libcrypto. Block itself was also allocated by libcrypto. I have been reading about issues with the version of libcrypto I have. https://curl.se/mail/lib-2016-08/0137.html. I don't think I will be able to upgrade the libcrypto package as that will affect lots of places within the codebase.
   What can I do as an  alternative ?

```
==15163== Invalid read of size 8
==15163==    at 0x4B5931C: lh_delete (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x4B5CF5F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x4B5DE53: ERR_remove_thread_state (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x5915BC7: soap_free (in /opt/MyC/lib/libjci_gsoap.so)
==15163==    by 0x672DFF: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x616D3B: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x61AAD7: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x61B69B: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x61159B: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x60CB93: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x60E08B: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x60D6FF: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==  Address 0x6e69b28 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==15163==    at 0x4849A00: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==15163==    by 0x4AE3F0B: CRYPTO_free (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x4B59337: lh_delete (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x4B5CF5F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x4B5DE53: ERR_remove_thread_state (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x50999B: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x50A473: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x50B437: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x5044CF: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x506433: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x50834F: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x5069B3: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==  Block was alloc'd at
==15163==    at 0x4848798: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==15163==    by 0x4AE3BEB: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x4B5928F: lh_insert (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x4B5CD23: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x4B5E017: ERR_get_state (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x4B5E46B: ERR_put_error (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x4B61B13: EVP_DecryptFinal_ex (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==15163==    by 0x49CBCD3: users::User::decrypt(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /opt/MyC/lib/libuserdatabase.so)
==15163==    by 0x49D19DB: users::User::authenticatePassword(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /opt/MyC/lib/libuserdatabase.so)
==15163==    by 0x532D01F: Security::authenticate(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (in /opt/MyC/lib/libonvif_utils.so)
==15163==    by 0x504437: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
==15163==    by 0x506433: ??? (in /opt/MyC/bin/MyProg)
```

Comment: First thing you need to do is to build your program with debug information enabled, add the `-g` flag when building. That will allow Valgrind to know the exact locations of the problems in your code, so it's much easier to trace.

Comment: The program is actually built with the -g flag. But I still get those ??? marks. Am not sure what is happening. Suspect something is not right in aarch64. I have never seen this problem with Ubuntu, for e..g

Comment: Then perhaps the build-system strips debug information after linking? Or perhaps the installation strips it? You might want to research that in more details, because it's much more likely that the root cause of the problem is in your code rather than in the libraries you use. That's not to say there aren't bugs in the libraries, there probably is, but it's less likely. :)

Comment: It is also not stripped. I am sure about that from the size of the binary as well.

Comment: Are you sure this is arm64? The addresses look too small for 64-bit, and they also don't seem to be 4-byte-aligned...

Comment: # uname -a
Linux Pro4-0001 4.14.183 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 9 21:38:42 BST 2021 aarch64 Flexible Linux
Yes aarch64 @Siguza

Comment: @badri that's just your kernel. Does `file /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0` tell you aarch64 as well?